# How does the British-Irish Visa Scheme (BIVS) work?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I am an Indian citizen and have applied for the Standard Visitor visa to the UK, and wish to travel to Ireland by using the BIVS scheme.

1. Do I need to fill up a separate application for BIVS endorsement or is it handed out automatically?
2. Also, If I enter the UK, and then travel to Ireland, can I re-enter the UK again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Do I need to fill up a separate application for BIVS endorsement or is
>   it handed out automatically?

There isn't a special form/checkbox to fill, but you must apply at a UK/Irish visa application center in India or China. Applications cannot be made at centers outside these two countries during the first phase of the scheme.

You will know your visa falls under the BIVS scheme if it carries a 'BIVS' endorsement.

> Also, If I enter the UK, and then travel to Ireland, can I re-enter the UK again?

If you have a British visitor visa and want to also visit Ireland, you must travel to the UK first (and vice-versa). After entering the Common Travel Area you are then free to travel freely between the two countries until your leave to enter (as shown on the passport stamp) expires.

You may also enter the UK first on an Irish visa in order to transit to Ireland. The opposite direction (entering the CTA through Ireland on a UK visa) is not allowed.

---

Sources: UK Government's [official BIVS page](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/british-irish-visa-scheme/british-irish-visa-scheme) and the Irish Government's [official BIVS explanation document](https://www.dfa.ie/media/embassychina/visas/BIVS-information-note-EN.pdf).

Comment: +1, nice one. Especially the 'official' links. They lend authority.

Answer (score 6):

You must note that, while applying for either visa you must show that you want to go to the other country also. Like if you are applying for an Irish visa you should show in your Irish visa application that you are also planning to go to England. Otherwise BIVS will not be endorsed on your visa stamp.

I had a bitter experience of same.