# Dublin airport: am I going through passport control?

Tags: transit, london, dublin, aer-lingus

I am traveling to London, UK (from Chicago, USA) by an Aer Lingus flight in about 2 weeks time. My first leg is Flight 122 from Chicago to Dublin and my second leg is Flight 154 from Dublin to London.

Both flights show as landing into and departing from Terminal 2 in Dublin.  I am wondering if I have to go through passport control?  The Dublin/T2 passport control [does not provide info on this](http://www.dublinairportt2.com/arriving-at-dublin-airport-t2/passport-control-at-dublin-airport-t2/).

I ask because I am wondering if my visas are enough to do this "transit" in Dublin.  I am an Indian citizen with an Indian passport, a US H1-B visa in my passport, a holder of a US green card AND a valid C type UK visitor visa valid until 2019.

I have read the following links on transit visas and the UK-Ireland visa:

[How does the British-Irish visa scheme work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/81243/how-does-the-british-irish-visa-scheme-work/81252#81252)

[How many visas will this itinerary require?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38666/how-many-visas-will-this-itinerary-require)

**Edit as to why this question is different:**

Is Dublin - London treated as a domestic flight?  If so, does passport control require me to have an Irish C visa, since Ireland is my first country of visit?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert It would seem that the answer you allude to also suggests that I will likely need to pass through passport control and shouldn't be alarmed.  +1 for finding this. Thank you.  I would link this also to your comment: https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=US&EM=IN&TR=IE&VT=00&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C.

Comment: Is your UK visa endorsed BIVS?

Comment: @phoog No.  IT is not.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: For the transit, I suppose it doesn't make a difference. But you can't use the visa to *visit* the Republic of Ireland under the BIVS because it is not a BIVS visa.